# The Jupyter Notebook cell keeps being run (never stops)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

In my coursework, I have to create the following picture (with one piece with no effect on it)

[image]

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

fnt = ImageFont.truetype('readonly/fanwood-webfont.ttf', 75)
# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif").convert('RGB')
drawing_object = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# build a list of 9 images which have different brightnesses
enhancer=ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
images=[]
x = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
    x += 1
    z = x 
    if x % 3 == 0 :
        z = 9
        drawing_object.rectangle((0,450,800,325), fill='black')
        drawing_object.text((20,350),'channel intensity 0.{}'.format(z), font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255))

    elif x % 3 == 1: 
        z = 1
        drawing_object.rectangle((0,450,800,325), fill='black')
        drawing_object.text((20,350),'channel intensity 0.{}'.format(z), font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255))

    else:
        z = 5
        drawing_object.rectangle((0,450,800,325), fill='black')
        drawing_object.text((20,350),'channel intensity 0.{}'.format(z), font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255))
    images.append(enhancer.enhance(10/10))

## create a contact sheet from different brightnesses
first_image=images[0]
contact_sheet=PIL.Image.new(first_image.mode, (first_image.width*3,first_image.height*3))
x=0
y=0

for img in images:
    # Lets paste the current image into the contact sheet
    
    contact_sheet.paste(img, (x, y) )
    
    #-->> I think the problem starts HERE <<--
    pixels = img.load()
    w = image.width
    h = image.height

    for x in range(3 * w):
        for y in range(3 * h):

            #-------0th row---------

            if x in range(0, w) and y in range(0, h): # grid[0,0]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,0,90)

            elif x in range(w, 2 * w) and y in range(0, h): # grid[0,1]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,0,50)

            elif x in range(2 * w, 3 * w) and y in range(0, h): # grid[0,2]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,0,10)

            #--------1st row---------


            elif x in range(0, w) and y in range(h, 2 * h): # grid[1,0]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (90,0,0)

            elif x in range(w, 2 * w) and y in range(h, 2 * h): # grid[1,1]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (50,0,90)

            elif x in range(2 * w, 3 * w) and y in range(h, 2 * h): # grid[1,2]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (10,0,0)

            #--------2nd row----------

            elif x in range(0, w) and y in range(2 * h, 3 * h): # grid[2,0]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,90,0)

            elif x in range(w, 2 * w) and y in range(2 * h, 3 * h): # grid[2,1]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,50,0)

            elif x in range(2 * w, 3 * w) and y in range(2 * h, 3 * h): # grid[2,2]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):        
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,10,0)
    
    # Now we update our X position. If it is going to be the width of the image, then we set it to 0
    # and update Y as well to point to the next "line" of the contact sheet.
    if x+first_image.width == contact_sheet.width:
        x=0
        y=y+first_image.height
    else:
        x=x+first_image.width



# resize and display the contact sheet
contact_sheet = contact_sheet.resize((int(contact_sheet.width/2),int(contact_sheet.height/2) ))


        
display(contact_sheet)
```

Here the `image` is the piece I am given. When I run this the Jupyter Notebook cell keeps being run `[*]`. Well, before I added the part of the code with `pixels` (after `#-->> I think the problem starts HERE <<--`) I had this grid exactly in the same view but without color effects. But now, I probably made some mistakes.

Comment: Could you explain in words, what you are trying to accomplish with the large for + ifelse code snippet.? There maybe more efficient ways of accomplishing that.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I'm trying to check what the current image `(x,y)` coordinates are, and according to this I want to change the pixel colors to make it look like the example picture.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Yes, definitely, I would love to have a more efficient way to do that! But I'm new to this imaging library and having difficulties to accomplish what I want efficiently...

Comment: ok, just one clarification, when you set the pixels to (0,0,50), what you are doing is that you are setting the values of the third channel of the image all to 50 right? So R, G, B becomes old_R, old_G, and B = 50?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Actually, the color now doesn't matter :) The problem is how to change the color.

Comment: yes but for my clarification could you give an example? because i think you can just update the whole array at once before building the grid.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Could you please help me improve my code, then?

Answer (score 0):

In the following part of the code -

```
            elif x in range(w, 2 * w) and y in range(2 * h, 3 * h): # grid[2,1]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,50,0)

            elif x in range(2 * w, 3 * w) and y in range(2 * h, 3 * h): # grid[2,2]
                for i in range(w):
                    for j in range(h):        
                        pixels[i, j] = (0,10,0)
```

... Aren't you just updating the whole range(w) and range(h) with values again and again? Is that what you want? You are checking if x and y are in a certain range, but then you are just writing each pixel with some value, instead of writing specific pixels.

Comment: I'm trying to check what the current image (x,y) coordinates are, and according to this, I want to change the pixel colors to make it look like the example picture. Since each time I change the pixels of the `image` (not `contact_sheet`) I was running the double for loop through `range(w)` and `range(h)` (the size of the original `image`)

Comment: When you change each pixel to (0,0,50), you are setting 2 channels to 0 and one channel to 50 meaning you will just get a Blue rectangle right?

Comment: yea but thats the problem isnt it. instead of getting an image 'colored' a certain way, you will just get a fixed color rectangle.

Comment: @AkshaySehgai Yes, it seems so. So, to fix this shall I set pixels to the tuple with `R,G` colors greater than 0?

Comment: nah that wont work, you need to use some numpy computes to do this in a vectorized manner